# Why is Cloud Run keeping 18 (very costly) containers idle all the time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a cloud run service. It's set up to handle sporadic scientific data processing tasks.

It has `min_instances=1`, `max_instances=40`. It'll sit with nothing active then burst up to 5-10 active containers a few times a week.

It's on the second generation runtime.

Our bills have been gradually increasing on GCP and we haven't thought much of it (because usage has increased); but recently we've done a bunch of work to streamline services and reduce costs - none of which resulted in the expected cost reductions. Drilling down in the cost SKU units (a UX nightmare, GCP really needs better ability to segment things) I discover that an overwhelming proportion of the cost is in Idle CPU and Idle RAM in Cloud Run.

Combing through the 10+ Cloud Run services we have, two of them are exhibiting a very weird behaviour: The number of idle instances is very high. In the case below, we have 18 machines running CONSTANTLY. These aren't cheap machines, either!

The [docs on Cloud Run autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling) are pretty clear: "To minimize the impact of cold starts, Cloud Run may keep some instances idle for a maximum of 15 minutes." but these containers are on permanently.

**With `max_instances=1` how can there possibly be 18 idle instances constantly up?**

[image: Cloud Run console for one of the offending services]

Answer (score 7):

Answering my own question after a postmortem.

The CI/CD system automatically releases a new revision of the service every time we merge to main on GitHub. 100% of traffic then gets directed to the new revision.

Each revision on Cloud Run is tagged with the code version of that release (eg `v0-1-2` for version `0.1.2`). Seems sensible, as it allows us to rollback straightforwardly to a given version.

Since we implemented that CI system, **we have made 18 releases**. It turns out that if you tag a revision, even if no traffic is going to that revision, Cloud Run will keep that revision alive, respecting its `min_instances` parameter.

This is to allow traffic to be routed to a specific revision via the `revision_url`, which is derived from the tag, regardless of the traffic routing settings.

But, that prevents us from turning off service revisions. There are only two ways to turn an old revision off so that your costs don't exponentiate over time:

- remove its tag (*which I find to be crazy because the tag is the way you know which revision is which*)
- copy the old revision's settings, duplicate them to a new revision, override `min_instances` to 0, release the new revision, apply the old tag to the new revision (completely disingenuous because it's not the same revision at all).
- never, ever set the `min_instances` parameter

If anyone from GCP reads this, **adding tags to something should not be the predicate of whether it's kept alive or not**. An `active` flag which we could change to activate/deactivate service revisions would be really beneficial.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion here because naming is hard. A Cloud Run Traffic Tag is not just an identifier like a git tag, it's used to give a revision a specific URL. See docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration#tags). You should only give tags to revisions that you want to be routable. If you want to identify a release, add an annotation instead. This is more clear in the [yaml format](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/yaml/v1) than the command line flags where you can see that tags are part of the traffic section and not the revision itself

Comment: Thanks BenK, yes I know that now and agree it's much clearer in the YAML spec. It doesn't help that annotations aren't available in the Console, which does refer to the offending things as "tags"... (I don't know about you, but I always use the console first to set up then transfer that to CI). I suspect this won't be the first time someone makes this error, and it was unbelievably costly. Live and learn!

Comment: @RahulBansal you're welcome. I've been trying quite hard to get GCP to acknowledge this problem, but to no avail as yet.

Comment: Surprising from Google. I deleted tags from a Cloud Run service and the idle container count came down immediately. However, there is another service which has lots of tags, but doesn't have so many container instances. Not sure why is there is different behaviour.

Also, it is really bad that GCP doesn't show the cost breakdown per service. This makes it so difficult to diagnose. @thclark

Comment: @RahulBansal yeah it's difficult to diagnose. If you have a service with lots of tags but fewer instances, I'd guess that some of those revisions were deployed with min_instances=0 and therefore are lying idle. Did you change the min_instances parameter at any point?